# How not to trigger phone call when click a number?

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter with bootstrap. 
In mobile(mine is iphone), the browser tries to trigger all number to phone call. 
I didn't any use html tags to do it like "tel:"
How can I prevent it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the format-detection meta tag key.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

More information about this and more, here;

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html